# Unwanted space in URLS in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, url

I have a list of 23000 URLs in an Excel sheet but these appear to have extra spaces in, therefore invalidating the urls.

I've tried a find and replace and excel doesn't recognise that there is an extra space in the cell.

This is an example of how I have pasted in the URL into the cell.

`/searchresult.asp/store/store/tskay/08REWA248`

but this is actually what is in the cell:

```
/searchresult.asp/store/store/
            tskay/08REWA248
```

and the url is spread over two lines.

I can make sure the text isn't wrapped in the cell and it all appears to be joined together, on a single line, but if I edit the cell in anyway, it jumps back to being split over tow cells.

I've tried pasting in notepad and I get the following URL:

```
/searchresult.asp/
            store/store/tskay/08REWA248FE/
```

With quotations and space, when I find and replace these and paste the clean url back into excel, it goes straight back into the old url with spaces.

I've also tried text to columns to break up the URL then concatenate it back but every time it goes straight back to the old URL with the extra spaces.

If I click into the cell and delete the space, it's fine, but with 23000 URLs, I can't possibly do this for them all and I can't find anything online to help!

How do I fix this?

Comment: You haven't really asked a question and we need to know a little more. We can only guess what you are seeking to resolve this. So, are you asking how to get Excel to allow you to paste the hyperlink properly? Or are you asking for a way to correct what it already there? Lastly, are these embedded hyperlinks or just text?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I need to know how i can keep this as one string of characters as i need to edit the cells. But currently, everytime i try to edit a cell, it reformats the text and splits it over two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text includes some carriage returns or line breaks. You can remove them in one go with a simple VBA procedure.

Be sure to save your sheet before following the steps below. (You'll want a backup in case this does something you don't expect and mangles your data.)

First, select the entire column of URLs. Then, open the VBA editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, and go to `Insert` >> `Module`. Paste the following code into the text field that is opened.

```vb
Sub FixURL()
Dim r As Range, URLs() As Variant
Dim rgx As Object
Set r = Selection
'Load contents of selection into an array
URLs = r.Value
'Set up a regular expression object for finding and replacing the line breaks and spaces
Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
rgx.Global = True
rgx.Pattern = "\r?\n[ \t]+"
'Remove problem text for each URL
For i = LBound(URLs, 1) To UBound(URLs, 1)
    URLs(i, 1) = rgx.Replace(URLs(i, 1), "")
Next i
'Print cleaned up URLs back to sheet
r.Value = URLs
End Sub
```

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute the code. This should remove the line breaks and extra spaces for all your URLs.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you so much for you're help. I would never have know what to do!